# How to open an URL on client side from AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to integrate tableau with Alexa using python. This will allow one to navigate the Tableau reports using voice commands. Based on the voice commands lambda script (python) will create a tableau server URL with the filters. It has to open up the URL in a window to the user. I don't need a clickable link here rather the tableau should open up directly when the user give some inputs to Alexa.

I have developed the python script which now creating the URL based on user input. But I couldn't find a way to open the same URL.Can anyone help me to fix this issue? What are the possible solutions here?(python packages like webbroswer, urllib etc are not working).

```
import webbrowser
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url='http://www.google.com'
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

I expected to open the URL in new browser window. But I am not getting it done.

Comment: Do you want to open that URL from the lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that you need to create a lambda layer to import the webbrowser package you want to use. For HTTP clients through, I recommend Requests (https://realpython.com/python-requests/).

Here's an example of how to use lambda layers: https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d

The doc for lambda layers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

> A layer is a ZIP archive that contains libraries, a custom runtime, or other dependencies. With layers, you can use libraries in your function without needing to include them in your deployment package.

Comment: There is no issues with importing the packages. Since lambda is server less platform we are not able to directly interact with the local system.